# Which to use : Custom datatype or TwoDArrayWritable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In order to emit 2 matrices as Key Value pairs:

```
Key  - Matrix A
```

`Value - Matrix B`.

Should I create a `custom` datatype or can directly go with `TwoDArrayWritable`? And what about the compareTo() method in custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll definitely need to write a custom class for your Key as `TwoDArrayWritable` doesn't implement `WritableComparable` (even if you just extend the `TwoDArrayWritable` class to add the interface and `compareTo` method).

As for whether you should use TwoDArrayWritable over a custom class - depends on a couple of factors (in my opinion):

- Are your arrays fixed in size / dimensions? If so i would say use a custom class so you can save performance and not re-create the arrays for each object deserialization call
- Do you arrays hold primitive types (int, double, float etc) - If so i would again say use a custom class so you don't have to worry about wrapping / unwrapping the primitive values from their wrapper writables (IntWritable, DoubleWritable etc) when performing matrix operations downstream

Comment: Thx Chris White for ur reply.My arrays are not with fixed size/dimension and but it will be double always. So it is better to create a Custom class for key and value right?

Comment: yes , i created [MatrixWritable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655071/custom-hadoop-key-and-value-get-values-in-a-two-dimensional-double-array)  class.but how to write CompareTo() method inorder to emit the key(matrix)

Comment: a compareTo method could be implemented in a number of ways, one method would be to initially compare the two dimension sizes for ordering, and if they match then drill down in to the matrix, one element at a time